# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10055)

Tags: mysql, perl

I am running three perl scripts sequentially. Each of them connects to a Mysql database multiple times, and either selects or updates the information contained in the database. After running these three scripts about 20~ times (& connecting/disconnecting from database many more times than this), I get the message 'Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10055).

I have read elsewhere that I could get it to reconnect to the database using mysql_auto_reconnect=1, however I'm not entirely sure that that is the problem. The Mysql server on my computer is still connected when the program crashes - I don't have to restart it. I wanted to understand why it is doing this, and also I'm not entirely sure how I put in '"mysql_auto_reconnect=1", as when I do this it tells me DBI->connect using old style syntax is deprecated.

```
my $dbh_m= DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:XXX","root","XXX","mysql_auto_reconnect=1")
```

or die("Error at select Trans: $DBI::errstr");

Do I also need to write this in every time I connect to the database? (Putting that into one of the connections doesn't solve the problem, I still get error messages from all the others - it doesn't begin to run again and then re-crash later). Is this a problem with me connecting/disconnecting to the database to many times?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error message do you get?

You should probably do something like:

```
my $dbh;
{
    local $@;
    do {
        eval { 
            $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:XXX", "root", "XXX", { mysql_auto_reconnect => 1 })
        };
        if ( $@ ) {
            warn "Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
            warn "Trying to reconnect in 5 sec.\n";
            sleep 5;
        }
    } while ($@);
}
```

Just in case that the database is not responding or there are too many connections.

Comment: Thanks, I have used this. It appears I am connecting/disconnecting to the database too many times, is it better to open the database and run multiple queries and only disconnect at the end of the program? Error I get is 'Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10055)', and that there is a problem with prepare

Comment: You should check your MySQL config file and increase the maximum connection limit if it is too low.
And, yeah - usually you need to connect to the database just once.

Answer (score 3):

```
DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:XXX", "root", "XXX", { mysql_auto_reconnect => 1 })
```

Comment: Even when putting that in, I still get the same error pop up (have put it on every single connection I'm making)

Comment: That may be, but the question you asked was on how to use `mysql_auto_reconnect`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not disconnecting from the mysql when your script finishes?

It is eat up resources in mysql. Please, check mysql logs for clue.

Regards,

Comment: I was connecting/disconnecting for every update/select statement I made, is this what I should be doing, or should I only disconnect at the end of the program? I thought this was happening because I was conn/disc too many times in a very short space of time Thanks!

Comment: If I were you I use one connect/disconnect in the program. Check the error after each database action (select/insert, etc). If is unsuccessfull then try to reconnect and execute the same statement.

Comment: One more thought: If you are not using autocommit maybe you are ate up resource with a large transaction.

Comment: thank you, I have changed it to one connect and so far I haven't encountered this problem again

Answer (score -1):

How to Fix MySQL Error 10055
To fix the problem you need to increase the number of dynamic ports.
Running the following Commands will give give you 50000 ports for dynamic use.

On Windows Server 2008 R2
Open command Prompt

Type the following
`netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=10000 num=50000`
Press Enter

Type the following
`netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport udp start=10000 num=50000`
Press Enter

Type the following
`netsh int ipv6 set dynamicport tcp start=10000 num=50000`
Press Enter

Type the following
`netsh int ipv6 set dynamicport udp start=10000 num=50000`
Press Enter

Comment: Copied without attribution from [here](http://blog.whitesites.com/How-to-Fix-MySQL-Error-10055__635140180116307813_blog.htm)